# How to optimize the animation of multiple images on page with Javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, html5-canvas

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelsucci/MncSm/171/). I load the images into the DOM and then animate them using a rotate plugin and some css. I'm having two problems:

1: I have the code resetting the 'top' css values to a negative number, and then continuing to increase them by one, so it looks like the snowflakes are falling from the top of the screen. For some snowflakes this works, but others just appear somewhere on the page.

2: The more snowflakes I have, the harder it is on my CPU. I know that having the images in the DOM isn't the best way, but I've tried putting the images in separate layers in the HTML5 Canvas, but that was even worse. Maybe there is an alternative to putting them in separate canvas layers?

Any ideas are appreciated. I'd love to package this up into a little jQuery plugin, but as of right now, this isn't happening if I can't get past this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the your combination of .each and setInterval is the issue. Instead of creating a timer for each flake, move them all on a single timer.